# Can I use a bin bash script to start two separate processes that need to remain running in two separate windows? UBUNTU 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04

I am referring to a proxy program that is required to be constantly running, and then a mining program.They both need their own window, and I am trying to make a script, so that I can run it on my HOST machine. I have a HOST machine and several rigs, if I have a rig that goes down, I want to SSH to my HOST machine and execute a script that will SSH to said rig, and perform said actions.

Running Ubuntu 14.04.3 server

```
#!bin/bash
cd ~/adl3
./atitweak -f 100 -p 20
cd ~/eth-proxy
sudo python ./eth-proxy.py
aticonfig —adapter=ALL —odsc=1060,300
aticonfig —adapter=ALL -odcc
cd ~/cpp-ethereum/build/ethminer
./ethminer —farm-recheck 150 —cl-local-work 256 -G -F http://127.0.0.1:8080/foxtrot
exit 0
```

Comment: Why do these programs need their own windows?

Comment: Hello Olaf, The processes really do not 'need' their own windows, but without visual indicators, I guess one would just wait a few minutes to see if everything runs properly. I've never done it without windows, but, without a doubt, it would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, possible with `setsid` command. I would rewrite your script as so:

```
#!bin/bash
cd ~/adl3
./atitweak -f 100 -p 20
cd ~/eth-proxy
setsid gnome-terminal -e 'sudo python ./eth-proxy.py'
aticonfig —adapter=ALL —odsc=1060,300
aticonfig —adapter=ALL -odcc
cd ~/cpp-ethereum/build/ethminer
setsid gnome-terminal -e './ethminer —farm-recheck 150 —cl-local-work 256 -G -F http://127.0.0.1:8080/foxtrot'
exit 0
```

Alternatively, one could use `nohup command &` like so. Note that `nohup` will write a file `nohup.out` to store your command's output, although redirection to `/dev/null` will prevent that.

If you need to hide the output of the script, add `&> /dev/null`  to the specific command that you want, or to the whole script on command line, like:

```
./my_script.sh &> /dev/null
```

If multiple commands need `sudo`, then append it to the beginning of the call to script on command-line, although then you will have to use full path instead of `~` expansion. In fact, it would save you several lines of script (and ensure proper execution, too) if you put full path instead of `~` in your script.

Comment: Serg, thank you very much for the response. When I launch the script, it fails to bring me another window with my miner, and the only thing that happens is eth-proxy runs in the window I ran the script in, along with everything else up to eth-proxy. The processes really do not 'need' their own windows, but without visual indicators, I guess one would just wait a few minutes to see if everything runs properly. I appreciate the extra advice about nohup

Comment: @NormanDunnagan  So both processes are text-only ones ?  In that case you might want write each command as Olaf shows. I'll edit my answer to include this

Answer (score 0):

On a standard Ubuntu Unity Desktop, you will have `gnome-terminal` available. On Kubuntu it might be `konsole`.

To start a new terminal/window with a command running inside, you may issue

```
gnome-terminal -e "sudo python ./eth-proxy.py"
```

or

```
konsole -e "sudo python ./eth-proxy.py"
```

The command line for `ethminer` looks similar.

---

As an alternative, you may also run the commands in the background and redirect the output like

```
python ./eth-proxy.py >/tmp/eth-proxy.log 2>&1 &
```

And then look at the output occasionally with `tail`

```
tail -f /tmp/eth-proxy.log
```